# Converting querystring to directory view

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use htaccess mod-rewrite to change some links I use. I am pretty good at other stuff(PHP & MySQL) but when it comes to this htaccess stuff my mind just leaves me.

Here is what I want:

Convert

```
mydomain.com/item.php?id=1
```

to

```
mydomain.com/item/1
```

and also if a page variable is also set like this:

Convert

```
mydomain.com/item.php?id=1&page=view
mydomain.com/item.php?id=1&page=remove
```

to

```
mydomain.com/item/view/1
mydomain.com/item/remove/1
```

But I also want .php extension to be hidden in whole website, not only for item.php. Like this:

```
mydomain.com/item.php
mydomain.com/user.php
```

to

```
mydomain.com/item
mydomain.com/users
```

Also if anyone visits the old boring links(item.php or item.php?id=1) they should be forwarded to their changed versions (/item or /item/1).

I did this to hide the php extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

And also did this to forward item.php with querystrings:

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/?$ /item.php?id=$1
```

They seem to work separately but not together. I just can't figure out how to make it work for all these different stuff together.

I also want to be able to use

```
$_GET['id'] and $_GET['page']
```

as normal in item.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need few more rules to make all this work together:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect /item.php?id=1&page=view to /item/view/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+item\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /item/%2/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# external redirect /item.php?id=1 to /item/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+item\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /item/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# external redirect /user.php to /user
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# internal rewrite /item/view/1 to /item.php?id=1&page=view
RewriteRule ^item/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ item.php?id=$2&page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# internal rewrite /item/1 to /item.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^item/(\d+)/?$ item.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# internal rewrite /user to /user.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ $1.php [L]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: Could you please explain what each line does? I don't want to be spoon fed. And thanks!

Comment: I've added some explanation and good references of mod_rewrite